# What test can I use for statistical significance?

Tags: categorical-data, intraclass-correlation

This is a graph of the distributions of population proportion (y-axis) by population density (x-axis) for four different modal ages of housing stock. The black line, which we are interested in, represents zip codes where modal decade for the build date of all housing units in that zip code is older than 1940. 
[image]

From the cumulative distribution, you can see that relatively much more of the population living in the oldest houses is living at a high density. I would like to prove that this is statistically significant.

What I know how to do is to prove that density and housing age is not independent. For example, if I break down the total number of people living in each age category by whether density is greater than or less than 2500 persons per km^2 (which is equal to Medford, Ma, San Leandro, Ca, or White Plains, NY, for some comparisons you might be familiar with), I get the following contigency table (numbers are in thousands)

```
            2000_newer  1970-1999  1940-1969  1939_older
lo density       60613     127707      39805       48412
hi density        1110       5447      12600       23991
```

I can use a Pearson's $\chi^2$ test for independence (using python).

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> a = [[60613, 127707, 39805, 48412], [1110, 5447, 12600, 23991]]
>>> chi2, p, df, exp = stats.chi2_contingency(a) 
>>> chi2, df, p
(46234.828950793169, 3, 0.0)
```

So far so good. With this low $p$-value, I can reject the null hypothesis that density and modal housing age are independent.

But I would like to say something stronger about the association between density and housing units older than 1940. 23% of houses are older than 1940, but 56% of houses in high density areas are that old.

**What test can I use to show a statistically significant correlation between a density and a specific age category?**

PS: I think what I am asking about is interclass correlation, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: My reading leads me to suppose that the age of the house is the independent variable and the population density at that house is the dependent. You may be making the analysis more complicated than necessary by applying arbitrary bins to the raw data, and you may get a clearer picture of the relationship from a simple scatter plot of density vs house age. (Assuming you have the actual house ages rather than just bin frequencies.)

Comment: @MichaelLew The data from the census bureau comes per zip code. So for each zip code, I have a single number density, and a distribution of housing units by decade built. So 3000 houses in 2000-2009; 4000 in 1990-1999, etc. From some other work, I theorize that best way to characterize a zip code relative to its housing age is to take the mode decade category. That is how the data gets binned.